# Cloud Run behind Cloudflare with orange cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloudflare, google-cloud-run

I have several services running on Cloud Run, and I use Cloudflare to manage the DNS entries. Previously, I did not use the orange cloud (active caching and other features provided by Cloudflare), but then I decided to activate the orange cloud. To my surprise, I began experiencing endless redirects (302).

Does this mean that I cannot enjoy the benefits of Cloudflare with Cloud Run under a domain?

Comment: Cloudflare works with Cloud Run just fine for me. What are the endless redirects? A simple curl command can show you the problem.

Comment: My bad, it is working now.

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as a community wiki so that the other can benefit from it

---

As mentioned by @John Hanley

> Cloudflare works with Cloud Run just fine for me. What are the endless redirects? A simple curl command can show you the problem

You may refer to this documentation:

- [Mapping custom domains](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/mapping-custom-domains)